# Avoiding typing html tags, pros and cons

Tags: php

Typing html is so boring and takes too much space and reduces code readability. What if to build such a function, and write all html with tag function. I know that just html is faster, but if to write html via tag function, how it will effect on site performance and page load time. General, is not bad to render html such a way? Thanks a lot.

```
<?php 
function tag($elem, $attr, $emb_elem = array()){
   $arr = explode("|", $attr);
   $attr_key = explode(',' , $arr[0]);
   $attr_val = explode(',', $arr[1]);
   $html = "<" . $elem;
   for($i=0; $i<count($attr_key); $i++){
      $html .= " " . $attr_key[$i] . "='". $attr_val[$i] . "'";
   }
   $html .= ">";
   for($i=0; $i<count($emb_elem); $i++){
      $html .= $emb_elem[$i];
   }
   $html .="</" . $elem . ">";
   return $html;
}

echo tag("p", "class,id|someclass,someid", array("some data"));
# output: <p class='someclass' id='someid'>some data</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rendering HTML this way will always be slower than not doing it – the question is how much this effects your site vs. how much time you save writing this way. Chances are it’s probably fine to write that way, many frameworks include similar methods.

If your site works this way, consider caching the pages so that it doesn’t have to render it every single page load.

You might be interested to read about [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/), which converts this into HTML:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript')
      if (foo) {
         bar()
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container
      - if (youAreUsingJade)
        p You are amazing
      - else
        p Get on it!
```

Comment: I want to keep things simple, in native code and clean, do not want to use any external libs to do that. Only worried about performance, not familiar with caching, but will check it out.

Comment: Well you could use an existing caching system, or build your own. Essentially, you just prepare the PHP page, but rather than echoing it out, you save it as an html file and just load that up instead. Sort of how Movable Type works, if you’ve ever used it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the HTML aspect from your PHP app will get you into trouble, as soon as you develop in a team with a dedicated web designer or as soon as you develop against predefined HTML layouts.

I highly recommend either using a template engine of choice (my favorite) or just have your HTML "nearby" your PHP code (much less flexible), if you want your skillset to include filling predesigned HTML with functionality.

Comment: I want to go this way and I work alone.(design and coding). Only worried how much I lose in performance